# Curiosity about DNS using dig command

Tags: web, dns, ip, cname, dig

I am curious, I am analyzing the DNS section for the website imgur.com. My doubt is that when I run "dig imgur.com" dig only returns an IP address, if I run again the same command dig returns another IP address or sometimes the same.

Another question:
By using dig www.imgur.com get a CNAME to another domain, is this normal?, Can someone explain to me?

Thanks

Comment: It is normal, but for more explanations you should probably go to https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should check [Round-robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS).

> Round Robin DNS is a technique of load distribution, load balancing,
>   or fault-tolerance provisioning multiple, redundant Internet Protocol
>   service hosts, e.g., Web server, FTP servers, by managing the Domain
>   Name System's (DNS) responses to address requests from client
>   computers according to an appropriate statistical model.
>
> In its simplest implementation, Round-robin DNS works by responding to
>   DNS requests not only with a single potential IP address, but with one
>   out of a list of potential IP addresses corresponding to several
>   servers that host identical services. The order in which IP addresses
>   from the list are returned is the basis for the term round robin. With
>   each DNS response, the IP address sequence in the list is permuted.
>   Usually, basic IP clients attempt connections with the first address
>   returned from a DNS query, so that on different connection attempts,
>   clients would receive service from different providers, thus
>   distributing the overall load among servers.